# Is it possible to have multiple Select Statements inside a CASE Statement in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, foxpro

I am trying to migrate Foxpro DB to SQL Server.. I have a CASE statement in Foxpro which works like this..

```
CASE *variable* = 1 
    SELECT * FROM TABLEA INTO CURSOR A
CASE *variable* = 2
    SELECT * FROM TABLEB INTO CURSOR B
CASE *variable* = 3
    SELECT * FROM TABLEC INTO CURSOR C
```

---

```
CASE *variable* = N
    SELECT * FROM TABLEN INTO CURSOR N
```

Is there a way to convert this CASE statement to SQL without using IF? I am assuming that in SQL Server CASE can be written only within a SELECT.

Thank you..

Comment: I suppose you could join all the tables like `JOIN tablea ON var = 1, JOIN tableb ON var = 2` etc. I wouldn't advise doing it (hence a comment rather than an answer) but it might provide some inspiration.

Comment: In t-sql `case` is not for control-of-flow; rather its used to return a single value, your going to have to use IF - It may be appropriate for foxpro but this kind of approach - cursors in particular - is rarely the best way to do things in SQL server

Comment: Why can't you use `IF`? There's no way to use CASE in SQL as far as I'm aware, because the result must be an `expression` which is a single-value.

Comment: I can use IF.. but I wanted to know if there's a way to work around CASE to meet this requirement

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make table dynamic in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350173/how-to-make-table-dynamic-in-sql)

Comment: A bigger question... are the table structures identical?  You might be best to just put this into a stored procedure...

Comment: No DRapp, the table structures are not identical.. I find using IF is the only ideal solution

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking:

```
SELECT * FROM IIF(var = 1, 'table1', IIF(var = 2, 'table2', 'table3')) INTO CURSOR IIF(var = 1, 'cur1', IIF(var = 2, 'cur2', 'cur3'))
```